# How to persist data for newly logged in users?

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, laravel-echo

I just wanted to ask on how can I persist data coming from previously fired events in Laravel. A sample scenario: admin updates a database record, it should then be broadcasted to all users(currently logged in or for users who will log in in the future). Currently, updates are received by the currently logged in users via listeners using laravel-echo and pusher-js. My problem is, when the event is fired and a user logs in to the app, that user isn't receiving the updated database record because the event is fired before the user logs in. I am using beyondcode's laravel-websocket package. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order to save notifications for users, you need to use database method,
see here : https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/notifications
So, first you need to migrate the table :

```
php artisan notifications:table
php artisan migrate
```

Then, in your notification file, set this :

```
public function toDatabase($notifiable)
{
    return [
        'foo_id' => $this->foo->id,
        'value' => $this->foo->value,
    ];
}
```

Finally, you may get unread notifications for a given user like this :

```
foreach ($user->unreadNotifications as $notification) {
    echo $notification->type;
}
```

Comment: Hi there. Is it necessary for me to use Notifications? I am using Laravel Events at the moment. A real life scenario is this, this is a betting platform I am currently developing. An admin, will set if the betting is open/close for a specific fight #. Now, when a betting is open, it should be broadcasted real time to all users for them to be able to place their bet.

Comment: At the moment, it is broadcasted only to users who are logged in at the time the Event is fired. Newly logged in users don't get the updates. They are unable to see the current fight number and  the betting status for that fight number.

Comment: What I want is, if the current fight number is 3, and a user logs in. The user must be able to see that the current fight is number 3 and see if its betting status is open or closed for him/her to be able to place bet on the said fight.